# Linux how to use rm and exclude switch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, switch-statement, rm

I was wondering how we can use linux **rm** command with **--exclude switch**?

For example like **grep** has exclude function when searching over the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one specific

```
rm `find . -name "safe_room*" ! -name "safe_rooms.php"`
```

I used it mainly for git

```
git rm `find . -name "safe_room*" ! -name "safe_rooms.php"`
```

Explanation:

`rm` - linux command for delete

**``** - the signs used within mysql. on keyboard CTRL + 7

`find . -name "safe_room*"`  - find everything with safe_room*

`!` - NOT logical operator

`-name "safe_rooms.php"` - exclude everything except safe_rooms.php

Hope this will help :)